# Bootstrap 5 migration issue with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5, webpack-5

I am trying to migrate from Bootstrap 4 to 5. When I do so dropdown, popper, and tooltip are not working. I am using bootstrap with webpack.

Bootstrap 5 styles are working correctly.

including popper with webpack as

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
  })
```

Importing tooltip and popover from bootstrap as

```js
import { Tooltip, Popover } from 'bootstrap';
```

HTML of popover

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Would be glad if someone can help me.

I am using https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Some syntax has changed between [4.6](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/popovers/) and [5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/). Specifically:

4.6 is using `... data-toggle="popover" ... data-content=...>`

5.0 is using `... data-bs-toggle="popover" ... data-bs-content=...`

Your HTML output is a mix between 4.6 and 5.0 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5, tooltips have to be triggered via Javascript. More details can be found at the [official Bootstrap documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#usage).

You may trigger and save all the tooltips in a page using the following code:

```js
const tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
)

let tooltip_list = tooltipTriggerList.map(
    function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    }
)
```